# Fonts in Intellij on JDK11+ are not clear

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, freetype

I am only able to run Intellij on openjdk8 currently as the fonts become unusable.  In my JDK11 installation, I copied my freetype ".so" files into the lib directory of the jdk, but that did not change anything.  It was my understanding that the JDK no longer bundles truetype fonts, so those libraries need to be manually copied.

Comment: Please always use JetBrains Runtime to run IntelliJ IDEA, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879.

Comment: I'm using the community edition on FreeBSD packages which is 2020.3.  I believe it is defaulting to the JDK installed by the system.  I will install it manually (and upgrade to 2021.2).

Comment: I installed the Linux version on FreeBSD and even with Linux compatibility enabled, it isn't running.  I suppose what I need to do is to update the Makefile in the port and update it to the 2021.2 CE build.  I was hoping someone else would have already done that.